# Replace slashes with dots in javascript regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a date and I want to replace all the slashes with dots. This is what I have but it's not working:

```
var TheDate = "3 / 29 / 2017";
TheDate = TheDate.replace(/'/'/g,'.');
alert(TheDate);
```

What's not right? There's a [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hLxjwwk8/) here to test.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Your expression should be `/\//g`**

```js
var d = "3 / 29 / 2017";
d = d.replace(/\//g,'.');
document.body.append(d);
```

Answer (score 2):

Replace `/'/'/g` with `/[/]/g`

- `/` - start of the regex
- `[/]` match characters inside square brackets
- `/g` end of the regex

Regex resources:

- http://regexr.com/
- https://regexone.com/

Answer (score 1):

Try this `TheDate.replace(/\//g, '.')`

Answer (score 1):

```
var TheDate = "3 / 29 / 2017";
TheDate = TheDate.replace(/\//g,'.');     
alert(TheDate);
```

You need to *escape* the `/` character. You do it by prepending it with a `\`.